# Combobox not showing Items while selecting the parameter from Listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my ComboBox to show a set of parameters every time I select something from the ListBox, but it is not showing anything inside the ComboBox.

This is what I have so far...

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add("BE");
        listBox4.Items.Add("MBA");
        listBox4.Items.Add("Pharmacy");
    }

    private void listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "BE")
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Add("CSE");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("IT");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("ME");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("EX");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("CE");
        }

        if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "Pharmacy")
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmaceutical Chemistry");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmacology");
        }

        if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "MBA")
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Retail Management");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("HR");
        }
    }
```

Here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm0w3.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you're filling `comboBox1` items when the selection of `comboBox1` is changed; you should probably move this code to the event handler above (`listBox4_SelectIndexChanged`). However it is a bit hard to say where the error is without to have the according `.Designer.cs` file at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You've placed your code in the wrong event.

```
        // This is where your code belongs.
        private void listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "BE")
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add("CSE");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("IT");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("ME");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("EX");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("CE");
            }
            if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "Pharmacy")
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmaceutical Chemistry");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmacology");
            }
            if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "MBA")
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add("Retail Management");
                comboBox1.Items.Add("HR");
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // THIS WAS THE WRONG PLACE
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should give your controls meaningful names so it's easier to determine what is coming from where.
2. Whenever populating the ComboBox, you should clear it first.
3. Most importantly, you are checking for the `SelectedIndexChanged` on the ComboBox instead of the ListBox. What happens if you move it up?

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox4.Items.Add("BE");
    listBox4.Items.Add("MBA");
    listBox4.Items.Add("Pharmacy");
}

private void listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "BE")
    {

        comboBox1.Items.Add("CSE");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("IT");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("ME");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("EX");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("CE");
    }

    if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "Pharmacy")
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmaceutical Chemistry");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmacology");
    }

    if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "MBA")
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Retail Management");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("HR");
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox4.Items.Add("BE");
        listBox4.Items.Add("MBA");
        listBox4.Items.Add("Pharmacy");
    }

    private void listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "BE")
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Add("CSE");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("IT");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("ME");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("EX");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("CE");
        }

        if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "Pharmacy")
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmaceutical Chemistry");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Pharmacology");
        }

        if ((string)listBox4.SelectedItem == "MBA")
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Retail Management");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("HR");
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: The wrong event has been handled.The event listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged should have the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should update (*remove* old and add new) `comboBox1.Items` on `listBox4` change:

```
   // Please, notice "listBox4"
   private void listBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     String selected = listBox4.SelectedItem as String;

     // we don't want blinking - too many re-draws
     combobox1.BeginUpdate();

     try { 
       //DONE: do not forget to remove old items
       combobox1.Items.Clear();

       if (selected == "BE") {
         combobox1.Items.AddRange("CSE", "IT", "ME", "EX", "CE");
       else if (selected == "Pharmacy") {
         combobox1.Items.AddRange("Pharmaceutical Chemistry", "Pharmacology");
       else if (selected == "MBA") 
         combobox1.Items.AddRange("Retail Management", "HR");  
     finally {
       combobox1.EndUpdate();
     }  
   }
```

And it seems that `comboBox1` is of no use, *at least now*:

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //TODO: put here logic on comboBox1 change, e.g. on "Retail Management" selection
 }
```